# How to average seperate cells that are not blank in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to select cells that are separated from each other (not in a range) and find the average of the ones that have a number in them. `AVERAGEIFS` does not seem to work because it only lets me average numbers in a range. What I want to do is `AVERAGE(A1,C1,E1)` and only include a cell if it is filled in.

Additionally, I want to average duration of `minutes:seconds` (`18:42`) in the same way but this is already hard enough and Google Sheets duration formats are disastrous.

How can I average numbers that are not right next to each other only if they are not blank, and how can I average duration in `mm:ss` at all?

Answer (score 2):

use `AVERAGE` instead of `AVERAGEIF`

```
=AVERAGE(A2,B3,C4)
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Comment: For duration, be sure to enter the values as HH:MM:SS